# Splitting Multiple Files in Windows

Tags: windows, storage-area-network, files

We have a 21TB LUN full of images that are approx 600K in size in multiple sub folders on the disk. We are trying to split the 21TB LUN into 8 smaller LUNs that are about 2.6TB a piece in order to process the images more effectively.

My question is how we can determine what 2.6TB is on the drive? What is the best tool to mark this data so we can copy it to the new smaller LUNs with robocopy or emcopy without overfilling the smaller LUNs? Is there a third-party tool that would be better suited for this task?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: What's the problem with using one larger LUN?

Comment: The LUN has about 16 Million images to process, but we want to split the LUN into smaller parts so we can attach them to more systems to process the images. Splitting the workload over 9 systems versus 1 system will greatly increase our throughput

Comment: What type of SAN are you working with?

Comment: VNX 5700 from EMC